# How to convert a JSON file and convert it to CSV keeping the headings using Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a file that is of type .gz and inside I have JSON objects like:

`input:`

```
{ "name":"John", "age":21, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Mike", "age":29, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Tim", "age":20, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Kim", "age":39, "gender":"female" }
```

Note: Notice there are no commas at end of each JSON obj.

I use the following to save it to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data_location = 's3://myBucket/myFolder'
raw_json_data = pd.read_json(data_location, lines=True)
raw_json_data.head(2)
```

Question: I want to convert it to CSV, maybe like this:

`expected output:`

```
name, age, gender
John, 21, male
Mike, 29, male
Tim, 20, male
Kim, 39, female
```

I used this but that **did not work** to give expected output - am I missing something?

```
df=pd.read_json(raw_json_data)
df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *I have a file that is of type .gz and inside I have JSON objects* is assumed to mean there is a `.gz` file, with a `.json` file inside.
- Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) methods to read the file in, and then split the rows into a `list` of `strings`

  - `Path('test.json')`: `'test.json()'` can be the path to the file if it's in a different directory.
- Convert the `strings` to `dicts` with `ast.literal_eval`

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from ast import literal_eval

# read the file in using the pathlib methods
text = Path('test.json').read_text().split('\n')

# map the strings to dicts
text = map(literal_eval, text)

# load the list of dicts into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(text)

# save to a csv
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

### Read from the `.gz` file

- Reading the lines with the `json` module is problematic because the data is not a properly formed `.json` file.

```py
import gzip
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# open the gzip file
with gzip.open('testing.json.gz', 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as zipfile:
    data = [literal_eval(v.strip()) for v in zipfile]

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# save to a csv
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can create dataframe with a column of the dictionaries

```
import json
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
{ "name":"John", "age":21, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Mike", "age":29, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Tim", "age":20, "gender":"male" }
{ "name":"Kim", "age":39, "gender":"female" } 
"""), delimiter='|', header=None)  # instead of StringIO part, you can have the path of input file

df    
                 0
0   { "name":"John", "age":21, "gender":"male" }
1   { "name":"Mike", "age":29, "gender":"male" }
2   { "name":"Tim", "age":20, "gender":"male" }
3   { "name":"Kim", "age":39, "gender":"female" }
```

You can use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to convert individual dictionaries to dataframe

```
def func(x):
    result = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(x.iloc[0]))
    return result

result = df.apply(func, axis=1)
result
0       name  age gender
0  John  21   male 
1       name  age gender
0  Mike  29   male 
2      name  age gender
0  Tim  20   male   
3      name  age  gender
0  Kim  39   female
dtype: object
```

The above output would be series of dataframe and to convert it to a single dataframe you can do following

```
pd.concat([r for r in result], ignore_index=True)

    name    age gender
0   John    21  male
1   Mike    29  male
2   Tim     20  male
3   Kim     39  female
```